# Implementing Holoeverywhere theme without ActionBarSherlock in my Android app

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

I am trying to implement the holoeverywhere theme in my app.

When I implement the holoeverywhere theme, I get a actionbar by default. I think it is because of Actionbarsherlock library. I was not aware of this library and have implemented my own actionbar of sorts. So, how do I disable the actionbar that comes up now.

If you need any relevant portions of my code, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the HoloEverywhere library included in my project, in the res>values>styles.xml file, there is a theme called Holo.Theme.Light.NoActionBar. I use that instead of Holo.Theme.Light which I used earlier. This fixed the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Removed ABS depends from HoloEverywhere... It's hard and don't supported by me.
First. Remove full library/src/com/actionbarsherlock from HE.
Second. Change library/resources/*.json to extend from standart android themes, not sherlock. Rebuild styles by `mvn resbuilder:styler`
Third. Remove fake-actionbar from PreferenceScreen code.
Fourth. Edit library/src/org/holoeverywhere/app/Activity and remove all related to ABS and remove Sherlock addon.
Fifth. Uncomment special block in library/res/values/attrs.xml. Straight from the top.
Sixth. Pray to Cthulhu and make a couple of tricks ears.

Once there was a branch nosherlock. Not popular.