# Android - Move to HoloEverywhere

Tags: java, android, eclipse, backwards-compatibility, android-holo-everywhere

I have a somewhat big Android project and now I'm starting to worry about backwards compatibility.
As such, I decided to use HoloEverywhere in my project so that my app looks well on older versions of Android.
From the looks of it, I now have to change every occurrence of 'android' with 'org.holoeverywhere' so that the definitions will be taken from HoloEverywhere.
Is there any way I can make this transition eaiser?
It'd be best if it could be easily configured without much tedious work.

Thanks in advance,
Tal Zion

Comment: I suppose all you need set Holo theme in AndroidManifest and choose custon View classes if define view in xml layout. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608539/error-importing-holoeverywhere  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476642/implementing-holoeverywhere-theme-without-actionbarsherlock-in-my-android-app

Comment: There are a few 'pre-processors' out there to change parts of a text file, if that is what you want to automate (changing import from android to xyz), but I cannot remember the name. saw it on stackoverflow so you can search here or google. I think only a few of the UI classes will need to be changed so maybe you need to specify certain packages and make sure others are left out. easiest way would be to copy a few test classes to try out the tool and your settings first.

Comment: If your on windows you can use Textpad or other notepad (notepad++ edit plus) to do the find replace. again be sure to test on a few representative files first

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to automate changing imports (changing import from android to HoloEverywhere):

On windows you can use UI like Textpad or other advanced notepad (notepad++ edit plus) to do the find replace. again be sure to test on a few representative files first. They have find replace in all open files.

On Unix/ linux/ Mac use sed or some other tool (there are ports for Windows too), plus linux with UI has good notepads too.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-replace-string-words-in-many-files/

Can use ant too http://www.javalobby.org/articles/ant-preprocessor/ especially good if already part of build and you know how to use it.